# ServiceStack.OrmLite Join with Skip and Take on Oracle DB

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to populate a grid that encompasses two different tables.  So I need:

1) Join functionality between the two tables.

2) Skip/Take to limit results.

3) Total count of rows in tables

I want to accomplish it using SqlExpression since it seems to be most supported in ServiceStack.OrmLite.  However, when I do a Skip and Take, it returns "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" since the two tables have some columns with the same name.

The code is as follows:

```
var dbCustomersQuery2 = db.From<USER>()
.LeftJoin<USER, USERPROFILE>((user, profile) => user.Id == profile.USER_ID)
.Where<USER>(user => user.USERNAME == "sangee.ram")
.Where<USERPROFILE>(profile => profile.PROFILEID == 442);
var result = db.Select<ViewModel>(dbCustomersQuery2.Skip(1).Take(5));
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.ExecReader(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ConvertToList[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.SqlList[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql, Object anonType)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.<>c__DisplayClass10`1.<Select>b__f(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Select[T](IDbConnection dbConn, ISqlExpression expression, Object anonType)
   at LO.Leads.UI.Tests.UserSecurityTests.CanQueryUserSecurity() in c:\Git\Cons.Orig.Lead\src\LO.Leads.UI\LO.Leads.UI.Tests\UserSecurityTests.cs:line 68
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you included the skip and take inside the last select command, once I moved that out I no longer get the exception.

```
var userQuery = db.From<USER>()
    .LeftJoin<USER, USERPROFILE>((user, profile) => user.Id == profile.USER_ID)
    .Where<USER>(user => user.USERNAME == "sangee.ram")
    .Where<USERPROFILE>(profile => Sql.In(profile.PROFILEID, new[] { 1, 441, 442, 452 }));

var result = db.Select<ViewModel>(userQuery)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(2);

Assert.NotNull(result);
```

When I ran this test it returned 2 rows (2nd and 3rd) out of a possible 4 rows.

Hope this helps,
Stephen